# Maven Unable to use archetype:generate if local repository of is changed from .m2

Tags: maven-2, maven-archetype

I am facing a strange issue. I have edited Maven `settings.xml` file in `M2_HOME/conf` and want the jars to get download to a place other than `{users.home}/.m2`.

I have pasted `<localRepository>G:/m2Repo</localRepository>` into `settings.xml`.

Now when I type `mvn archetype:generate`, I get following error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Searching repository for plugin with prefix: 'archetype'.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] The plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin' does not exist or no valid version could be found
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: The plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin' does not exist or no valid version could be found
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.verifyPlugin(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:1569)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:1851)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.segmentTaskListByAggregationNeeds(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:462)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:175)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.version.PluginVersionNotFoundException: The plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin' does not exist or no valid version could be found
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.version.DefaultPluginVersionManager.resolvePluginVersion(DefaultPluginVersionManager.java:229)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.version.DefaultPluginVersionManager.resolvePluginVersion(DefaultPluginVersionManager.java:91)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.verifyPlugin(DefaultPluginManager.java:179)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.loadPluginDescriptor(DefaultPluginManager.java:1642)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.verifyPlugin(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:1540)
        ... 15 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

This can happen if the artifact or metadata got corrupted. Try to clean out your local repo by deleting all versions of the `maven-archetype-plugin` (**including** metadata and pom files).

Then execute `archetype:generate` again.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by removing the entry for localRepository in settings.xml . 
Starting to generate the archetype again
Move the downloaded artifacts the place where we wanted G:/m2Repo
start generating the artifact again. 
Now the jars etc would get downloaded to the new place automatically

The problem which I can think is that I had deleted the {users.home}/.m2 folder also and 
that was preventing the download .

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.

**Environment**:

```
`OS`: Mac Seirra 10.12.6.  
`Java version` :1.8.0_144
`Maven` 3.5.4
```

**Solution** :

```
rm -rf ~/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/
```

Answer (score -1):

My error was:

(http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2):

> Plugin not found in any plugin repository

Solution :

```
1. go to .m2 folder > repository
2. delete all folders inside this 
3. try the following command again:

mvn archetype:generate
```

Comment: deleting `.m2/repository` is a big decision. I wont use a sword where scalpel works.